# Sometimes my Thinkpad won't wake up from sleep

Tags: 18.04, suspend, thinkpad

I have a [ThinkPad E335](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/e330_e335_hmm_en_0b48602_04.pdf) running Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS with the 5.0.0-25 kernel, and for the most part it works fine, however sometimes when I put my laptop in suspend, it won't come back on. Screen stays black, I can't switch to consoles via <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

I can't see if my laptop's accessing disk, as I don't have HDD activity indicator on it. I will try to replicate this error to provide logs.

**Edit 1**: External keyboard doesn't work either, so it's not brightness problem. Looks like it's frozen, and nothing's happening. Here's the [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/sCK38U5T) after system reboot.

Comment: If you attach an external USB keyboard to your Thinkpad, can you replicate the issue? Please click [edit] and report your findings; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: I have a similar problem with two different Thinkpad models. In my case it is just the graphics card that doesn't restore the screen luminosity. When this happens I just hit the key to increase display luminosity to make the screen available again.

Comment: This is happening me now using a Thinkpad T530 for 3 years, with Debian 9 stable. I think I updated the headers, so probably that's the problem. I will check the `dmesg` next time.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is still relevant: I had a similar problem on my Thinkpad T460, but only after "upgrading" to the HWE stack. I switched back now and hope the problem is gone.

In my case though, the notebook did not wake up at all, the light signalling the status was always indicating that it was still sleeping.